# How do you find a coefficient for a polynomial whose roots are given?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, polynomials, roots, cubics

If the polynomial $x^3 + 2x^2 + kx - 2$ has three real roots: $a, 1/a,$ and $b$, then what is $k$?

I've tried writing the polynomial with the roots filled in, and thus making a system of equations then trying some algebraic manipulations. However, I couldn't find a solution.

So any help or a suggestion to a method that I'm missing is appreciated.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Write it as a product of monomials and expand, or use Vieta’s formulas.

Comment: Could you detail what you tried?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If the roots of a monic polynomial $p(x)$ are $\alpha$, $\beta$, and $\gamma$, then$$p(x)=(x-\alpha)(x-\beta)(x-\gamma)$$and therefore the coefficient of $x$ is $\alpha\beta+\beta\gamma+\gamma\alpha$. Can you take it from here?

Comment: I tried this actually, and then filled it in $k$ and tried to isolate $a$ or $b$ but it didn't work... I got something like $b = a - a^{-1} - 2$ but don't know if it's correct and how to proceed.

Comment: @Surzilla How did you get that? You should have got $1+ba+\frac ba$.

Comment: @ Surzilla $k=-7$ See my answer below

Comment: @JoséCarlosSantos I also got that for $k$, I meant that after filling in $k$ in $x^3 + 2x^2 + kx-2$ and then filling in $a$, getting $a^3 + 2a^2 + (1+ba+\frac{b}{a})a - 2 = 0$, and filling in $\frac{1}{a}$ and $b$ to obtain three equations in total, I don't know what to do with these equations to obtain values for $a$ or $b$. Sorry for the confusion.

Comment: @Surzilla And the product of the roots is $2$, that is, $b=2$. And the sum of the roots is $-2$, that is $a+\frac1a+b=-2$. But, since you know $b$, this gives you $a$. And, since you know $a$ and $b$, you know the value of $k$.

Comment: @JoséCarlosSantos can you know the product of the roots is $2$ and the sum is $-2$ using only high school math (as was intended for the problem)? Perhaps I'm missing something obvious.

Comment: You know that\begin{align}x^3+2x^2+kx-2&=(x-\alpha)(x-\beta)(x-\gamma)\\&=x^3-(\alpha+\beta+\gamma)x^2+(\alpha\beta+\alpha\gamma+\beta\gamma)x-\alpha\beta\gamma.\end{align}Therefore, $\alpha+\beta+\gamma=-2$ and $\alpha\beta\gamma=2$.

Comment: @JoséCarlosSantos alright, I got it now. Thanks for your help and patience.

Comment: I'm glad I could help.

Answer (score 1):

$P(x)=(x-a)(x-\frac{1}{a})(x-b)$

$b=2$ since $(-a)\times\frac{1}{a}\times b=-2$

Hence $(x-a)(x-\frac{1}{a})(x-2)=x^3+2x^2+kx-2$

Expand the left side, you get $x^3+(-2-a-\frac{1}{a})x^2+(\frac{2}{a}+2a+1)x-2$

$-2-a-\frac{1}{a}=2$ and $\frac{2}{a}+2a+1=k$

The first equation, $\frac{1}{a}=-a-4$. Substitute  $\frac{1}{a}$ with $-a-4$ in equation 2

$2(-a-4)+2a+1=k$

$-2a-8+2a+1=k$

$k=-7$

Comment: `b=2 ... Hence ...` You don't need any of what follows. Once you determined that $\,b=2\,$ is a root, just plug it back into the original equation and solve $\,2^3 + 2 \cdot 2^2 + k \cdot 2 - 2 = 0\,$ for $\,k\,$.

Comment: How do you know $b=2$? If you obtained it from the method @dxiv mentioned, I haven't learned this yet. The problem can be solved in high school mathematics (as it's from a calibration test for prospective engineering students), I just don't see how.

Comment: ＠dxiv Oh, that's right !!

Comment: @Surzilla If you expand $(x-a)(x-\frac{1}{a})(x-b)$, you will find that the constant term should be $(-a)\times \frac{1}{a}\times (-b)$, which is equal to the constant of the given polynomial (-2). Since $(-a)\times \frac{1}{a}\times (-b)=-b$, $-b=-2$. Therefore, $b=2$.

Answer (score 0):

Hint: the product of the roots is $a \cdot \dfrac{1}{a}\cdot b = 2$ by [Vieta's relations](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vieta%27s_formulas), so one of the roots is $b=2\,$.